# Pipeline within a pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have three jobs on my jenkins server. One of them triggers the other two, and all three of them run one after another in a sequence. All are free style jobs.

Now, I want to convert all three jobs into pipeline jobs. So in my case, all three jobs will have their own separate pipelines and there would be an outer pipeline that will show me the three jobs running one after another. Is it possible at all to have a situation where the first job completes building in pipeline, then triggers the second job which runs in its own pipeline stages and then the third job also completes all the stages in its pipeline?

From the outside there would be a larger open pipeline : Job1->Job2->Job3
and on the inside there'd be smaller pipelines with each stage of each job like Clone->Build->Report Generation->.....

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

at the end of Job1 pipline when it is success put this code

```
build 'JOB_NAME_2', propagate: false, wait: false
```

then at the end of Job2 pipline put this code

```
build 'JOB_NAME_3', propagate: false, wait: false
```

shape propogate and wait according to your needs.
to check please refer to Pipeline Syntax in your jenkins instance

```
/pipeline-syntax/
```

Comment: A more clear example, that has parameters, might be:

`
build(job: 'exact job name', parameters: [
                            [$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'SOMEPARAM', value: 'XYZ']
                            ]
                        )
`

Comment: yeah that's right, for case when your jobs have parameters